# Expression must be a list type: Set<Id>

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm writing a test class to test for a failure, I've already written the test for success and it covers most of the class however, since I have error catches I need to test for success and failure too.

In @testSetup I created Opportunity records already. In my test I need to retrieve the Opportunity id in a set so I can pass it to my class as it expects an incoming set. I wrote this to grab one of the Opps:

```
Set<Id> oppyIds = (new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1])).keyset();
```

I need to create an OpportunityLineItem record so I went with this:

```
OpportunityLineItem oliTest = new OpportunityLineItem();
        oliTest.OpportunityId = oppyIds[0];
```

When I compile I get the error

> Expression must be a list type Set

If I change the line to oliTest.OpportunityId = oppyIds[0].id I get:

> Illegal assignment from Set to Id

How can I pass the set Id to be the field Id?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sets are not an ordered collection, so you cannot index it in that way. What you'll want to do here is define `List<Id> idList = new List<Id>(opptyIds);` and then you'll be able to access index 0 with `idList[0]`

Comment: Adding to that, its only Lists and arrays that can be used interchangeably, a privilege that's only possible in SF and not its predecessor, Java.